# Disable RTL if no translations available

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left

I have Arabic translations in application. The app also supports RTL layout. When the user uses Arabic everything looks fine. The problem is that when I change local to e.q. Persian where they use RTL but I don't provide translation for this langue my layout looks like a mess.

**How to disable RTL if no translations is available for current local?**

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this. Did no try it myself but was thinking around this.

```
Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
   if (config.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
      //if you do not have a string defined here you can disable it here
        config.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);

    }
```